# How to specify informat when importing xlsx

Tags: sas

I am   importing excel `xlsx` file. it contains some `date` values. i want to specify `informat`

```
proc import out=test 
/* i tried input and informat but it did not work */
datafile="C:\Users\ALCopy.xlsx" 
dbms=excel replace;
range="Test1$"; 
getnames=no ;
mixed=no;
scantext=yes;
usedate=no;
scantime=no; 
run;
```

I tried `userdate=yes` but this did not work for all date columns . Many of then were treated as string columns . How can I set up `informat` for each column individually ?

---

i tried changing it later with `informat` statement but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DBSASTYPE` option to specify how a column is brought in.

```
DBDSOPTS="DBSASTYPE=(datevar='DATE')";
```

This doesn't always work depending on *why* it is not automatically coming in right, but it sometimes does.