# Failed to change character into date in SAS

Tags: date, format, sas, informat

I imported 5 excel files into SAS and there are some dates formatted as 8/3/1989 originally and formatted into 03Aug1989 (DATE9.) which is what I really want. However, on 1 file the dates failed to converted into DATE9. and it is read as $CHAR10 when I read the log. I tried several ways to reformat it into DATE9 but failed.

1. I tried to change all informat/format/input into DATE9. instead of $CHAR10 but failed, the results are all empty (.)
2. I tried  DateNew=input (Date,DATE9.);   but it didn't work either.

Any comment?

Thanks!

Comment: Try the suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924104/how-to-specify-informat-when-importing-xlsx and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Joe's suggestion in the comment should be plan A. But occasionally built-in SAS format-specifying options don't work and you still end up with a string. If that's where you're at, here's a good fallback:

```
data test;
format imported_date $char10.;
imported_date = "8/3/1989";

month = scan(imported_date, 1, "/")*1;
day = scan(imported_date, 2, "/")*1;
year = scan(imported_date, 3, "/")*1;

date_datefmt = mdy(month,day,year);
format date_datefmt date9.;
run;
```

Comment: Why not just use `input(imported_date,mmddyy10.)`?  And why are you using the automatic numeric conversion here - again, use input.

Comment: Someone in my office actually asked me OP's question yesterday, and I referred him to your link above. That didn't work for him, and he had already tried input(imported_date, mmddyy10.) (with many different date formats). Input() worked for most imported files but returned blanks for some. So input() (with various date formats used) was his plan A, DBDSOPTS was plan B. Importing with a libname/data-step using "DBSASTYPE=(datevar='DATE')" was his plan C. When all that failed he defaulted to what I posted which is pretty fail-safe, so I thought I'd share it.

Comment: Your code above only works if `input(...mmddyy10.)` works, though (ie, it only works if it is month/day/year).

Comment: Hi Joe, my mistake, I had thought my friend used mmddyy10, but in fact he had only used ANYDTDTM. Which should be able to read mmddyy10 data according to SAS documentation, but wasn't for some reason. When he did (just now) replace the scan() code with input(_,mmddyy10.) it did work, so I don't in fact have an example where scan() worked and input() didn't. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: The problem with anydtdte (rather than dtm) is that it sometimes assumes the data is ddmmyy rather than mmddyy depending on what dates it encounters first.

Comment: ANYDTDTM. should be a last resort rather than the goto informat most people use it as.  Good code will use the most restrictive informat possible, and fail should it encounter unexpected results.  Any other method and you can't be sure what is going into your data.  GIGO.